# How can I create an alias for c compiler with Shell Script?

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to know if is possible create an alias with Shell Script which turn easy my C compilation.

I tried to add it into my `.bashrc` file, however it didn't work how I wish, returning a bad message which said that does not existed any command like that.

`alias xpto='gcc prototipo.c -o prototipo.exe $(pkg-config –cflags –libs allegro-5) -lallegro -lallegro_main -lallegro_image -lallegro_ttf -lallegro_font -lallegro_primitives -lallegro_audio -lallegro_acodec -std=c99'`

Comment: Log out and in again, or `source .bashrc`, for the change to take effect

Comment: That's not about programming within the rules of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message may be about the command itself.  The below commands worked for me but gave an error about the missing file.

```
machine1:/u/user1>cat .bashrc
alias xpto='gcc prototipo.c -o prototipo.exe $(pkg-config –cflags –libs allegro-5) -lallegro -lallegro_main -lallegro_image -lallegro_ttf -lallegro_font -lallegro_primitives -lallegro_audio -lallegro_acodec -std=c99'
machine1:/u/user1>bash
machine1:/u/user1>xpto
gcc: prototipo.c: No such file or directory
machine1:/u/user1>
```